# SelectionChanged Event of WPF comboBox is not firing if it has same items in it

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

if i m using following type of code then SelectionChanged Event of WPF comboBox is not firing

```
cmbFunctionsList.Items.Add("sameItem");
cmbFunctionsList.Items.Add("sameItem");
cmbFunctionsList.Items.Add("sameItem");
cmbFunctionsList.Items.Add("sameItem");
cmbFunctionsList.Items.Add("sameItem");
```

Is there any work around of this.

Comment: i have also done this using some other work around by assigning data table obj to cmbFunctionsList ItemSource and adding a new Guid to each row of data table :( but i think approach by Carl is much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
ComboBoxItem newItem = new ComboBoxItem();
newItem.Content = "same item";
cmbFunctionsList.Items.Add(newItem);
```

Idea taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

WPF Combo Boxes will not change the selected item if the currently selected item and the new one that selected are considered equal by the `object.Equals()` method called on the newly selected object (i.e `newlyslected.Equals(currentlySelected)`).

In this case the `string.Equals` method is returning true since the values of strings are equal

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly a strange issue. The only workaround I can think of is storing the index of the combobox, and every time anything happens to it (KeyDown, LeftMouseButtonDown etc.) check the stored index against the new index. Something like:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //populate combo box
    lastKnownIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
}

int lastKnownIndex;

private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) // and all other possible input events
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex != lastKnownIndex)
    {
        //do stuff
        lastKnownIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

There's probably a far more elegant solution but that should work.

EDIT: Should also probably let MSFT know that WPF is broken ;)