# What event handler to use for ComboBox Item Selected (Selected Item not necessarily changed)

Tags: c#, wpf

**Goal:** issue an event when items in a combobox drop down list is selected.

**Problem:** Using "SelectionChanged", however, if the user choose the same item as the item is currently being selected then the selection is not changed and therefore this event will not be triggered.

**Question:** What other event handler(or other ways) I may use to issue an event regardless of the selected item is changed or not as long as the mouse clicked on that item and that item is being selected.

(Clarification: Problem is how to trigger "something" when the same item is being selected again. No duplicates in the drop down list. Scenario: first time select item 1,close drop down. And then again, open drop down box and select item 1 when some function are triggered.)

**Solution**: for now there seems to be no straight-forward solution to do this. But according to each individual project, there can be ways to work around it. (Please update if there are indeed good ways to do this). Thanks.

Comment: Don't use events in WPF. Create a proper ViewModel and use DataBinding and simple properties instead.

Comment: Does it **have** to be an event? WPF provides data binding, which would allow you do bind the `SelectedItem` of your ComboBox to a property your view's DataContext

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I tried this approach after seeing your comment. What I did was: Bind SelectedItem (also tried SelectedIndex) to a property in ViewModel and in the setter do some of the logic that I would do if having a  "SelectionChanged" event. However, this still could not solve the problem that when item selected is same as before, setter will not be triggered. I might be missing something here.

Comment: Well what sort of logic would you need to run if the same item is selected? The state didn't change, so what exactly would your application reflect?

Comment: Not tested but make the items buttons then you can handle the button clicked event.

Comment: Yeah, that could be a way to work around it. For now, i guess there is no straight-forward solution to that. The actual project itself is a little cumbersome to explain @Ryan. Thanks for the help guys

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22224172/wpf-selectionchanged-to-same-value) suggests trying `DropDownClosed`.

Comment: I would propose you tag this with UWP too, since the problem is still valid. I was looking for such a topic for a long time!

Answer (score 40):

I had the same question and I finally found the answer:

You need to handle BOTH the SelectionChanged event and the DropDownClosed like this:

In XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbSelect" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" DropDownClosed="ComboBox_DropDownClosed">
    <ComboBoxItem>1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

In C#:

```
private bool handle = true;
private void ComboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if(handle)Handle();
  handle = true;
}

private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
  ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
  handle = !cmb.IsDropDownOpen;
  Handle();
}

private void Handle() {
  switch (cmbSelect.SelectedItem.ToString().Split(new string[] { ": " }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last())
  { 
      case "1":
          //Handle for the first combobox
          break;
      case "2":
          //Handle for the second combobox
          break;
      case "3":
          //Handle for the third combobox
          break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

For me `ComboBox.DropDownClosed` Event did it.

```
private void cbValueType_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbValueType.SelectedIndex == someIntValue) //sel ind already updated
        {
            // change sel Index of other Combo for example
            cbDataType.SelectedIndex = someotherIntValue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use "ComboBoxItem.PreviewMouseDown" event. So each time when mouse is down on some item this event will be fired.

To add this event in XAML use "ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle" like in next example:

```html
   <ComboBox x:Name="MyBox"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
        SelectedValue="{Binding MyItem, Mode=OneWayToSource}" >
        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <EventSetter Event="ComboBoxItem.PreviewMouseDown"
                    Handler="cmbItem_PreviewMouseDown"/>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   </ComboBox>
```

and handle it as usual

```cs
void cmbItem_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //...do your item selection code here...
}
```

Thanks to [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b3fdc20d-a6ee-4b38-a534-c5cc5a0df6fc/combobox-fire-selectionchanged-when-reselecting-same-item?forum=wpf)

Comment: how in the handler we get the clicked comboboxitem value (not the selected...only the clicked one )

Comment: `MyBox.SelectedItem` or `MyBox.SelectedValue`. As another [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mouse.previewmousedown?view=netframework-4.0) states `PreviewMouseDown` event _"Occurs when any mouse button is depressed"._ So, that time `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue` are already set.

Comment: You can also use ComboBox.SelectedItem = ((ComboBoxItem)sender).Content;
(Particularly if you have SelectedValuePath set in your ComboBox XAML)

Answer (score 9):

I hope that you will find helpfull the following trick.

You can bind both the events

```
combobox.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
combobox.DropDownOpened += OnDropDownOpened;
```

And force selected item to null inside the OnDropDownOpened

```
private void OnDropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    combobox.SelectedItem = null;
}
```

And do what you need with the item inside the OnSelectionChanged.
The OnSelectionChanged will be raised every time you will open the combobox, but you can check if SelectedItem is null inside the method and skip the command

```
private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (combobox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
           //Do something with the selected item
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

For UWP (Windows Store) apps none of the above will work (PointerPressed doesn't fire; no Preview, DropDownClosed or SelectedIndexChanged events exist)

I had to resort to a transparent button overlaying the ComboBox (but not its drop down arrow). When you press on the arrow, the list drops down as usual and the Combo Box's SelectionChanged event fires. When you click anywhere else on the Combo Box the transparent button's click event fires allowing you to re-select the Combo Box's current value.

Some working XAML code:

```
                <Grid x:Name="ComboOverlay" Margin="0,0,5,0"> <!--See comments in code behind at ClickedComboButValueHasntChanged event handler-->
                    <ComboBox x:Name="NewFunctionSelect" Width="97" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Functions}"
                          SelectedItem="{x:Bind ChosenFunction}" SelectionChanged="Function_SelectionChanged"/>
                    <Button x:Name="OldFunctionClick" Height="30" Width="73" Background="Transparent" Click="ClickedComboButValueHasntChanged"/>
                </Grid>
```

Some working C# code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// It is impossible to simply click a ComboBox to select the shown value again. It always drops down the list of options but
    ///     doesn't raise SelectionChanged event if the value selected from the list is the same as before
    ///     
    /// To handle this, a transparent button is overlaid over the ComboBox (but not its dropdown arrow) to allow reselecting the old value
    /// Thus clicking over the dropdown arrow allows the user to select a new option from the list, but
    ///     clicking anywhere else in the Combo re-selects the previous value
    /// </summary>
    private void ClickedComboButValueHasntChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //You could also dummy up a SelectionChangedEvent event and raise it to invoke Function_SelectionChanged handler, below 
        FunctionEntered(NewFunctionSelect.SelectedValue as string);
    }

    private void Function_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FunctionEntered(e.AddedItems[0] as string);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try "`SelectedIndexChanged`", it will trigger the event even if the same item is selected.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I did not see this option from combobox though, is this C# WPF?

Comment: I just noticed it was WPF, in that case the issue was already posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738899/selectionchanged-event-of-wpf-combobox-is-not-firing-if-it-has-same-items-in-it

Comment: that's a useful post. (I am assuming in the post, the "same item" are checked to be equal using their memory address and therefore distinguish between duplicates) However in my combo box list, there are no duplicates. What I want is: if I select item 1 the first time. And then I open the drop down and select item 1 again, a function can be triggered.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void OnDropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
     if (combobox.SelectedItem == null) return;
     // Do actions
}
```

(Edit by Dominique): a more straightforward solution might be:

```
private void OnDropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem != null) // when you don't check anything,
                                                 // this is "null"
    {
        // Do_Actions
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

For UWP, I tried a different approach. I extended the ComboBox class, and processed the SelectionChanged and OnKeyUp events on the ComboBox as well as the Tapped event on the ComboBoxItems. In cases where I get a Tapped event or an Enter or Space key without first getting a SelectionChanged then I know the current item has been re-selected and I respond accordingly.

```
class ExtendedComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public ExtendedComboBox()
    {
        SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
    }

    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        ComboBoxItem cItem = element as ComboBoxItem;
        if (cItem != null)
        {
            cItem.Tapped += OnItemTapped;
        }

        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // if the user hits the Enter or Space to select an item, then consider this a "reselect" operation
        if ((e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Space || e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter) && !isSelectionChanged)
        {
            // handle re-select logic here
        }

        isSelectionChanged = false;

        base.OnKeyUp(e);
    }

    // track whether or not the ComboBox has received a SelectionChanged notification
    // in cases where it has not yet we get a Tapped or KeyUp notification we will want to consider that a "re-select"
    bool isSelectionChanged = false;
    private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        isSelectionChanged = true;
    }

    private void OnItemTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!isSelectionChanged)
        {
            // indicates that an item was re-selected  - handle logic here
        }

        isSelectionChanged = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you post this on a question with the tag Wpf?

Answer (score 0):

This problem bugs me for a long time since none of the work-around worked for me :(

But good news is, the following method works fine for my application.

The basic idea is to register a `EventManager` in `App.xmal.cs` to sniff `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent` for all `ComboBoxItem`, then trigger the `SelectionChangedEvent` if the selecting item is the same as the selected item, i.e. **the selection is performed without changing index**.

In `App.xmal.cs`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        // raise selection change event even when there's no change in index
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(ComboBoxItem), UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
                                          new MouseButtonEventHandler(ComboBoxSelfSelection), true);

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }

    private static void ComboBoxSelfSelection(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as ComboBoxItem;

        if (item == null) return;

        // find the combobox where the item resides
        var comboBox = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item) as ComboBox;

        if (comboBox == null) return;

        // fire SelectionChangedEvent if two value are the same
        if ((string)comboBox.SelectedValue == (string)item.Content)
        {
            comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = false;
            comboBox.RaiseEvent(new SelectionChangedEventArgs(Selector.SelectionChangedEvent, new ListItem(), new ListItem()));
        }
    }
}
```

Then, for all combo boxes, register `SelectionChangedEvent` in a normal way:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding BindList}"
          SelectionChanged="YourSelectionChangedEventHandler"/>
```

Now, if two indices are different, nothing special but the ordinary event handling process; if two indices are the same, the Mouse Event on the item will first be handled, and thus trigger the `SelectionChangedEvent`. In this way, both situations will trigger `SelectionChangedEvent` :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a DependencyObject for attaching to a ComboBox.

It records the currently selected item when the dropdown is opened, and then fires SelectionChanged event if the same index is still selected when the dropdown is closed. It may need to be modified for it to work with Keyboard selection.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MyNamespace 
{
    public class ComboAlwaysFireSelection : DependencyObject
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ActiveProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Active",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(ComboAlwaysFireSelection),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, ActivePropertyChanged));

        private static void ActivePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = d as ComboBox;
            if (element == null) 
                return;

            if ((e.NewValue as bool?).GetValueOrDefault(false))
            {
                element.DropDownClosed += ElementOnDropDownClosed;
                element.DropDownOpened += ElementOnDropDownOpened;
            }
            else
            {
                element.DropDownClosed -= ElementOnDropDownClosed;
                element.DropDownOpened -= ElementOnDropDownOpened;
            }
        }

        private static void ElementOnDropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            _selectedIndex = ((ComboBox) sender).SelectedIndex;
        }

        private static int _selectedIndex;

        private static void ElementOnDropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var comboBox = ((ComboBox) sender);
            if (comboBox.SelectedIndex == _selectedIndex)
            {
                comboBox.RaiseEvent(new SelectionChangedEventArgs(Selector.SelectionChangedEvent, new ListItemCollection(), new ListItemCollection()));
            }
        }

        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForChildrenAttribute(IncludeDescendants = false)]
        [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(ComboBox))]
        public static bool GetActive(DependencyObject @object)
        {
            return (bool)@object.GetValue(ActiveProperty);
        }

        public static void SetActive(DependencyObject @object, bool value)
        {
            @object.SetValue(ActiveProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

and add your namespace prefix to make it accessible.

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:ut="clr-namespace:MyNamespace" ></UserControl>
```

and then you need to attach it like so

```
<ComboBox ut:ComboAlwaysFireSelection.Active="True" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)` event
[here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: this is WPF not Winforms!

Answer (score 0):

Every ComboBoxItem instance has PreviewMouseDown event. If you will subscribe your custom handler on this event on every ComboBoxItem you will have opportunity to handle every click on the dropdown list.

```
// Subscribe on ComboBoxItem-s events.
comboBox.Items.Cast<ComboBoxItem>().ToList().ForEach(i => i.PreviewMouseDown += ComboBoxItem_PreviewMouseDown);

private void ComboBoxItem_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     // your handler logic...         
}
```

Comment: the problem is that if your items are changing this won't work

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, just add if (e.AddedItems.Count == 0) return; in the beggining of function like:

```
        private  void ComboBox_Symbols_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count == 0) 
        return;
        //Some Other Codes
    }
```